# Gmock linker error ==> multiple definition (using cmake)

Tags: c++, cmake, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I am facing error within googlemock and I can compile and run the project using eclipse and my cmake with only one file Test.cpp using the following code, but error using my mock class. Please I need help. Thanks a lot.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace testing;

class mxDriverInterface
{
    public:
        mxDriverInterface(){}
        virtual ~mxDriverInterface(){}
        virtual bool isReady(void) = 0;
};

class mxDriverImpl : public mxDriverInterface
{
     public:
        mxDriverImpl(){}
        bool isReady(){return true;}
};

// A mock mxDriver class
class MockMxDriver : public mxDriverInterface
{
    public:
       MockMxDriver(){}
       virtual ~MockMxDriver(){}
       MOCK_METHOD0(isReady, bool());
};

TEST(checkMockMx, instance)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(4 != 5);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

===========================================================================

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from checkMockMx
[ RUN      ] checkMockMx.instance
[       OK ] checkMockMx.instance (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from checkMockMx (0 ms total)
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

==========================================================================

But just instanciating my MockMxDriver class like that :

```
TEST(checkMockMx, instance)
{
```

> MockMxDriver mockMxDriver;

```
EXPECT_TRUE(4 != 5);
```

}

## ...the project ends up with the following error :

```
11:22:27 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project Test ****
"..\\..\\build.bat" all 
PROJECT: Test
PROJECT: Test
CMAKE_SRC: C:/_SW/myProject/tests
PROJ_SRC: C:/_SW/myProject/tests
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/_SW/myProject/tests/test_src/build/googletest-download
[1/6] Performing update step for 'googletest'
Current branch master is up to date.
[2/6] No configure step for 'googletest'
[3/6] No build step for 'googletest'
[4/6] No install step for 'googletest'
[5/6] No test step for 'googletest'
[6/6] Completed 'googletest'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/_SW/myProject/tests/test_src/build
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test_src/boostTest.cpp.obj
[2/2] Linking CXX executable Test.exe
FAILED: Test.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\MinGW\bin\g++ -g3 -Wall -O0 -fmessage-length=0   CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test_src/Test.cpp.obj  -o Test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libTest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.a googletest-build/googlemock/libgmock.a -lpthread googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.obj): In function `ZN7testing8internal5Mutex4LockEv':

C:\_SW\myProject\tests\test_src\build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:275: multiple definition of `testing::internal::Mutex::Lock()'

CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test_src/Test.cpp.obj:C:\_SW\myProject\tests\test_src\build/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:2262: first defined here

googletest-build/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.obj): In function `ZN7testing8internal5Mutex6UnlockEv':

C:\_SW\myProject\tests\test_src\build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:281: multiple definition of `testing::internal::Mutex::Unlock()'

CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test_src/Test.cpp.obj:C:\_SW\myProject\tests\test_src\build/../Test.cpp:119: first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

11:22:36 Build Finished (took 9s.37ms)
```

Here are the CMAKE files :
CMakeLists.txt for my test project which uses CMakeLists.txt.in for googleTest.

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.3)
SET(MY_PROJECT_NAME Test)

project(${MY_PROJECT_NAME})

message("PROJECT: " ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}) 
message("PROJECT: " ${PROJECT_NAME})  
message("CMAKE_SRC: " ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) 
message("PROJ_SRC: " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}) 

add_definitions(-DGTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY=1)
add_definitions(-DBUIlD_SHARED_LIBS=ON)
add_definitions(-Dgmock_build_tests=ON)

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download" )
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download" )

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This adds
# the following targets: gtest, gtest_main, gmock
# and gmock_main
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
                 "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build")

# The gtest/gmock targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
    include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
                        "${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()

# set boost installation and compiler paths:
SET(BOOST_ROOT C:/MinGW/boost_1_64_0)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/g++)
SET(PROJECT_TEST_EXEC ${MY_PROJECT_NAME}.exe)
SET(REGEX_EXEC_LIB ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/regex-2.7-lib/lib/libregex.dll.a)
add_definitions(-D__CYGWIN__=1)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g3 -Wall -O0 -fmessage-length=0" CACHE STRING "project cxx flags" FORCE) 
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "-g3 -Wall -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99" ) 


SET(SOURCES
    test_src/Test.cpp
    )

include_directories (${BOOST_ROOT}  
                     ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_src/mocks   # test directory     
                    )

add_executable(${MY_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${MY_PROJECT_NAME} gtest)
target_link_libraries(${MY_PROJECT_NAME} gmock)

# create target to start test and format result for jenkins
add_custom_target(jenkins.test COMMAND ${PROJECT_TEST_EXEC} --log_format=XML --log_sink=results.xml --log_level=all --report_level=no --result_code=no  )
```

And my CMakeLists.txt.in

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

Comment: You use `cmake` tag, so you use googletest via CMake, don't you? If so, show your `CMakeLists.txt` code (add this code into the question post).

Comment: Looks like you messed `googletest` with your configuration options. First, try to build googletest using its `CMakeLists.txt` directly (without external project or so). If this will succeed, remove everything from your project except building googletest: your executable, Boost and so, and try again. Hints: 1. `add_definitions(-DGTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY=1)` creates *compiler definition*, not a CMake setting. Use same construct as you use for `gtest_force_shared_crt`. 2. `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` should be set at the beginning of the project. Some projects (including googletest) checks it.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion. I can compiled and used google test alone and with my project. The linker error occurs when I include only the file which contents gmock macro (**MOCK_METHODn**). I know that google mock frame has been included because I had an error when comment out this in cmake : **target_link_libraries(${MY_PROJECT_NAME} gmock)** .